# Egyptian Fractions

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

**Overview:**

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction): An Egyptian fraction is the sum of distinct unit fractions. That is, each fraction in the expression has a numerator equal to 1 and a denominator that is a positive integer, and all the denominators differ from each other. The value of an expression of this type is a positive rational number a/b. Every positive rational number can be represented by an Egyptian fraction.

**Challenge:**

Write the shortest function that will return the values of all the denominators for the *smallest set* of unit fractions that add up to a given fraction.

**Rules/Constraints:**

- Input will be two positive integer values.

  - This can be on `STDIN`, `argv`, comma separated, space delimited, or any other method you prefer.
- The first input value shall be the numerator and the second input value the denominator.
- The first input value shall be less than the second.
- The output may include a value(s) that exceeds the memory limitations of your system/language (RAM, MAX_INT, or whatever other code/system constraints exist). If this happens, simply truncate the result at the highest possible value and note that somehow (i.e. `...`).
- The output should be able to handle a denominator value up to at least 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup>-1, signed 32-bit `int`).

  - A higher value (`long`, etc.) is perfectly acceptable.
- The output shall be a listing of all values of denominators of the smallest set of  unit fractions found (or the fractions themselves, i.e. `1/2`).
- The output shall be ordered ascending according to the value of the denominator (descending by the value of the fraction).
- The output can be delimited any way you wish, but there must be some character between so as to differentiate one value from the next.
- This is code golf, so the shortest solution wins.

**Exmaples:**

- Input 1:

  `43, 48`
- Output 1:

  `2, 3, 16`
- Input 2:

  `8/11`
- Output 2:

  `1/2 1/6 1/22 1/66`
- Input 3:

  `5 121`
- Output 3:

  `33 121 363`

Comment: Input/Output 2 should be `8, 11` and `2, 6, 22, 66` right?

Comment: Either/Or; they are equivalent. I'd like to leave the formatting up to the creator of the solution.

Comment: Is any minimum length fraction OK?  For instance, 8/11 is also 1/2+1/5+1/37+1/4070.

Comment: @KeithRandall That would be fine as well. 4 is still 4.

Comment: A possible suggestion, to remove abiguity, would be to require the smallest set of unit fractions with the smallest final denominator. For example, `1/2 1/6 1/22 1/66` would be preferable `1/2 1/5 1/37 1/4070` for the input `8/11`.

Comment: I suggest adding `5/121 = 1/33+1/121+1/363` to the test cases. All greedy programs (including mine) give 5 fractions for it. Example taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions).

Comment: @ugoren Added...

Comment: @primo I think that if there are multiple minimums, then whichever can be found would be acceptable. If one algorithm can be written with fewer characters as a result, I would not want to hinder that solution.

Comment: @Gaffi Can I ask for some clarity on the requirement that the program handles cases that "exceeds the memory limitations of your system"? Does this mean that the program is not at all allowed to fail due to memory exhaustion? My (current) entry uses a fixed amount of memory, but it does fail if an internal value exceeds MAX_INT. Is it acceptable to treat that as the same thing? (And if so, is there a minimum upper limit that the program must accept? Presumably there is; otherwise `return x==y?"1":"..."` would be a winning entry.)

Comment: @breadbox You should account for both memory limitations and MAX_INT (or whatever other code/system constraints exist). Also, you make a good point about exiting prematurely... Fixing question.

Comment: @userunknown Yup, it does. Fixed.

Comment: Gave +1 since I've actually learned about Egyptian fractions in a History of Math course (and had to do math with with them, as well as finding the fractional sums like this problem.) A nice and creative challenge.

Comment: @primo If reducing ambiguity were important for answers, it'd make more sense to me to make the sum of the denominators as low as possible.

Comment: Fun fact: the Egyptians also had an independent representation of 2/3 as a single "fraction".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Common Lisp, 137 chars

```
(defun z(n)(labels((i(n s r)(cond((= n 0)r)((< n(/ 1 s))(i n(ceiling(/ 1 n))r))(t(i(- n(/ 1 s))(1+ s)(cons s r))))))(reverse(i n 2'()))))
```

(z 43/48) -> (2 3 16)

(z 8/11) -> (2 5 37 4070)

(z 5/121) -> (25 757 763309 873960180913 1527612795642093418846225)

No need to worry about huge numbers, or handling fractional notation!

Comment: (defun z(n)(labels((i(n s r)(cond((= n 0)r)((< n(/ 1 s))(i n(ceiling(/ 1 n))r))(t(i(- n(/ 1 s))(1+ s)(cons s r))))))(reverse(i n 2'()))))


(z 43/48)
Show not result in tio... What I have to use for print the result?

Comment: (print (z 103/333) )
 return one list of 5 numbers but would exist one list of 4 numbers as: 1/4,1/18,1/333,1/1332. So the above function would not return the minimum.

Answer (score 8):

### Python 2, <s>169</s> 167 chars

```
x,y=input()
def R(n,a,b):
 if n<2:return[b/a][b%a:]
 for m in range((b+a-1)/a,b*n/a):
  L=R(n-1,a*m-b,m*b)
  if L:return[m]+L
n=L=0
while not L:n+=1;L=R(n,x,y)
print L
```

Takes comma-separated args on stdin and prints a python list on stdout.

```
$ echo 8,11 | ./egypt.py 
[2, 5, 37, 4070]
```

Comment: 1. I think you can save two chars by using tab on the second indentation level. 2. The script doesn't indicate truncation due to exceeding system memory limitations.

Comment: In Tio Your code goes out of memory for just 103/45533

Comment: Instead in Ideone your code goes in run time error for the same input 103,45533: Runtime error #stdin #stdout #stderr 0.89s 99264KB

Answer (score 4):

### PHP 82 bytes

```
<?for(fscanf(STDIN,"%d%d",$a,$b);$a;)++$i<$b/$a||printf("$i ",$a=$a*$i-$b,$b*=$i);
```

This could be made shorter, but the current numerator and denominator need to be keep as whole numbers to avoid floating point rounding error (instead of keeping the current fraction).

Sample usage:

```
$ echo 43 48 | php egyptian-fraction.php
2 3 16
$ echo 8 11 | php egyptian-fraction.php
2 5 37 4070
```

Comment: Comma operator emulated as useless arguments to printf? I should save this trick somewhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a [Greedy Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions), so it won't always give the smallest set of fractions. If you run it with input like `5 121` or `31 311`, it will give the wrong answer (after a very long time).

Comment: @grc 31/311 -> {a[1]->11,a[2]->115,a[3]->13570,a[4]->46422970}

Answer (score 4):

### C, <strike>163</strike> 177 chars

**6/6**: At last, the program now correctly handles truncation in all cases. It took a lot more chars than I was hoping for, but it was worth it. The program should 100% adhere to the problem requirements now.

```
d[99],c,z;
r(p,q,n,i){for(c=n+q%p<2,i=q/p;c?d[c++]=i,0:++i<n*q/p;)q>~0U/2/i?c=2:r(i*p-q,i*q,n-1);}
main(a,b){for(scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);!c;r(a,b,++z));while(--c)printf("%d\n",d[c]);}
```

The program takes the numerator and denominator on standard input. The denominators are printed to standard output, one per line. Truncated output is indicated by printing a zero denominator at the end of the list:

```
$ ./a.out
2020 2064
2
3
7
402
242004

$ ./a.out
6745 7604
2
3
19
937
1007747
0
```

The denominators in the second example sum to 95485142815 / 107645519046, which differs from 6745 / 7604 by roughly 1e-14.

Comment: Again, I think this is a greedy algorithm.

Comment: The outermost loop explores all possible answers of N denominators before it begins testing answers of N+1 denominators. You can call it greedy, I suppose, but I believe it fulfills the stated problem.

Comment: Sorry, I take that back. It doesn't follow the greedy solution, but I have found that it isn't completely accurate for some input (`31 311` for example).

Comment: `31 311` overflows, but the program fails to flag it.

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 61 chars

Input from STDIN, comma separated.
Output to STDOUT, newline separated.
Doesn't always return the shortest representation (e.g. for 5/121).

```
a,b=input()
while a:
    i=(b+a-1)/a
    print"1/%d"%i
    a,b=a*i-b,i*b
```

Characters counted without unneeded newlines (i.e. joining all lines within the `while` using `;`).
The fraction is `a/b`.
`i` is `b/a` rounded up, so I know `1/i <= a/b`.
After printing `1/i`, I replace `a/b` with `a/b - 1/i`, which is `(a*i-b)/(i*b)`.

Comment: I want to vote this up, since it *is* so small, but it's just missing that one piece!

Comment: I want to fix this one piece, but then it won't be so small... I have a feeling I'll just reinvent Keith Randall's solution.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 94 bytes

```
n,d,i;main(){scanf("%i%i",&n,&d);for(i=1;n>0&++i>0;){if(n*i>=d)printf("%i ",i),n=n*i-d,d*=i;}}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##HctBCoQwDAXQq0jB0mgEuxsI7V2kofIXxkHdiWfvDK4fr0xrKa0ZK0O2BRboPstiNbgePRx7Y68kdT8CUhTLsx9H5FnoRg02ICel7wG73tI5BrGlP0zKOiTI87T26WL8AQ)

edit: A shorter version of the code was posted in the comments so I replaced it. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! This is a [tag:code-golf] competition, so the objective is to [make your code as short as possible](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13945/31716). It looks like there are lots of things you could do to make your code shorter. For example, you could removed all the unnecessary whitespace from your answer.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Thank you sir, understood and done.

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! Could you perhaps add a [TryItOnline-link](https://tio.run/#) with test code for the test cases in the challenge? Also, some things you could golf: `for(i=2;n>0&&i>0;i++)` can be `for(i=1;n>0&++i>0;)`; the brackets of the for-loop can be removed (because it only has the `if` inside); `d=d*i;` can be `d*=i;`; and I'm not entirely sure, but I think `#include <stdio.h>` can be without spaces: `#include<stdio.h>`. Oh, and it might be interesting to read [Tips for golfing in C](https://tinyurl.com/ycedgqn7) and [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://tinyurl.com/y8kzo4vm)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for the tips.

Comment: [94 bytes](https://tio.run/##HctBCoQwDAXQq0jB0mgEuxsI7V2kofIXxkHdiWfvDK4fr0xrKa0ZK0O2BRboPstiNbgePRx7Y68kdT8CUhTLsx9H5FnoRg02ICel7wG73tI5BrGlP0zKOiTI87T26WL8AQ).

Comment: In Ideone C web compiler server, the input 103/333 return as solution 4 17 2059 9324800 343340800 one length 5 solution, but it would be one array of length 4 that would be good too: 1/4,1/18,1/333,1/1332; so that not return the minimum

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é├WüsOΩ↨÷╬6H╒σw[▐â
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82c35781734fea17f6ce3648d5e5775bde83&i=43%2F48%0A8%2F11%0A5%2F121%0A55%2F89&a=1&m=2)

At each step, it tries to minimize the subsequent *numerator*.  It seems to work, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 7 bytes

```apl
⌂efract
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qW9CjtgmGRhbmXEBOQACQY2zy/1FPU2paUWJyyf80oMCj3r5HXc2Petc86t1yaL3xo7aJQKXBQc5AMsTDM/i/ibFCmoKJBZcFkDI05DIFUUaGAA)

From *some* reason, Dyalog APL has a builtin for this.

Takes the numerator and denominator on the left and the right

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ḟo=⁰ΣṖİ\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9odXNr///huJ9vPeKBsM6j4bmWxLBc////NDMvNDg)

Larger denominators take very long, as we are calculating the powerset of an infinite list.

Takes input as a fraction `a/b`.

### Explanation

```
ḟo=⁰ΣṖİ\
      İ\ Infinite list [1,1/2,1/3...]
     Ṗ   Powerset
ḟo       first sublist which satisfies:
    Σ    sum
  =⁰     equals input?
```

Answer (score 0):

## AXIOM, 753 bytes

```
L==>List FRAC INT
macro  M(q)==if c<m or(c=m and m<999 and reduce(max,map(denom,q))<xv)then(m:=c;a:=q;xv:=reduce(max,map(denom,a)))
f(x,n)==(y:=x;a:L:=[];c:=0;q:=denom x;q:=q^4;for i in n.. repeat((c:=c+1)>50=>(a:=[];break);1/i>y=>1;member?(1/i,a)=>1;a:=concat(a,1/i);(y:=y-1/i)=0=>break;numer(y)=1 and ~member?(y,a)=>(a:=concat(a,y);break);(i:=floor(1/y))>q=>(a:=[];break));a)
h(x:FRAC INT):L==(a:L:=[];x>1=>a;numer(x)=1=>[x];n:=max(2,floor(1/x));xv:=m:=999;d:=denom x;zd:=divisors d;z:=copy zd;for i in 2..30 repeat z:=concat(z,i*zd);d:=min(10*d,n+9*m);for i in n..d repeat((c:=maxIndex(b:=f(x,i)))=0=>1;c>m+1=>1;M(b);v:=reduce(+,delete(b,1));for j in z repeat((c:=1+maxIndex(q:=f(v,j)))=1=>1;member?(b.1,q)=>1;q:=concat(b.1,q);M(q)));reverse(sort a))
```

The idea would be apply the "Greedy Algorithm" with different initial points,
and save the list that has minimum length. But not always it would find the min solution with
less difined: "array A will be less than array B if and only if A has few elements of B,
or if the number of elements of A is the same of number of elements of B, than A it is less than B
if the more little element of A is bigger as number, than the more little element of B".
Ungolfed and test

```
-- this would be the "Greedy Algorithm"
fracR(x,n)==
   y:=x;a:L:=[];c:=0;q:=denom x;q:=q^4
   for i in n.. repeat
      (c:=c+1)>50   =>(a:=[];break)
      1/i>y         =>1
      member?(1/i,a)=>1
      a:=concat(a,1/i)
      (y:=y-1/i)=0  =>break
      numer(y)=1 and ~member?(y,a)=>(a:=concat(a,y);break)
      (i:=floor(1/y))>q           =>(a:=[];break)
   a

-- Return one List a=[1/x1,...,1/xn] with xn PI and x=r/s=reduce(+,a) or return [] for fail
Frazione2SommaReciproci(x:FRAC INT):L==
    a:L:=[]
    x>1       =>a
    numer(x)=1=>[x]
    n:=max(2,floor(1/x));xv:=m:=999;d:=denom x;zd:=divisors d;z:=copy zd
    for i in 2..30 repeat z:=concat(z,i*zd)
    d:=min(10*d,n+9*m) 
    for i in n..d repeat
        (c:=maxIndex(b:=fracR(x,i)))=0=>1 
        c>m+1                         =>1
        M(b)
        v:=reduce(+,delete(b,1))
        for j in z repeat
              (c:=1+maxIndex(q:=fracR(v,j)))=1=>1
              member?(b.1,q)                  =>1
              q:=concat(b.1,q)
              M(q) 
    reverse(sort a)

(7) -> [[i,h(i)] for i in [1/23,2/23,43/48,8/11,5/121,2020/2064,6745/7604,77/79,732/733]]
   (7)
      1   1      2   1  1      43  1 1  1      8  1 1  1  1
   [[--,[--]], [--,[--,---]], [--,[-,-,--]], [--,[-,-,--,--]],
     23  23     23  12 276     48  2 3 16     11  2 6 22 66
      5    1  1   1      505  1 1 1  1    1
    [---,[--,---,---]], [---,[-,-,-,---,----]],
     121  33 121 363     516  2 3 7 602 1204
     6745  1 1  1  1    1      1       77  1 1 1  1  1   1
    [----,[-,-,--,---,-----,------]], [--,[-,-,-,--,---,---]],
     7604  2 3 19 950 72238 570300     79  2 3 8 79 474 632
     732  1 1 1  1   1    1     1
    [---,[-,-,-,--,----,-----,-----]]]
     733  2 3 7 45 7330 20524 26388
                                                      Type: List List Any
       Time: 0.07 (IN) + 200.50 (EV) + 0.03 (OT) + 9.28 (GC) = 209.88 sec
(8) -> h(124547787/123456789456123456)
   (8)
        1             1                         1
   [---------, ---------------, ---------------------------------,
    991247326  140441667310032  613970685539400439432280360548704
                                     1
    -------------------------------------------------------------------]
    3855153765004125533560441957890277453240310786542602992016409976384
                                              Type: List Fraction Integer
                     Time: 17.73 (EV) + 0.02 (OT) + 1.08 (GC) = 18.83 sec
(9) -> h(27538/27539)
         1 1 1  1  1    1      1        1
   (9)  [-,-,-,--,---,-----,------,----------]
         2 3 7 52 225 10332 826170 1100871525
                                              Type: List Fraction Integer
                     Time: 0.02 (IN) + 28.08 (EV) + 1.28 (GC) = 29.38 sec
```

reference and numbers from: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fractions/egyptian.html

for add something, this below would be  the one optimized for find min length  fraction that has the max denominator less (and not optimized for lengh)

```
L==>List FRAC INT

-- this would be the "Greedy Algorithm"
fracR(x,n)==
   y:=x;a:L:=[];c:=0;q:=denom x;q:=q^20
   for i in n.. repeat
      (c:=c+1)>1000  =>(a:=[];break)
      1/i>y          =>1
      member?(1/i,a) =>1
      a:=concat(a,1/i)
      (y:=y-1/i)=0  =>break
      numer(y)=1 and ~member?(y,a)=>(a:=concat(a,y);break)
      (i:=floor(1/y))>q           =>(a:=[];break)
   a

-- Return one List a=[1/x1,...,1/xn] with xn PI and x=r/s=reduce(+,a) or return [] for fail
Frazione2SommaReciproci(x:FRAC INT):L==
    a:L:=[]
    x>1       =>a
    numer(x)=1=>[x]
    n:=max(2,floor(1/x));xv:=m:=999;d:=denom x;zd:=divisors d;z:=copy zd; 
    w1:= if d>1.e10 then 1000 else 300; w2:= if d>1.e10 then 1000 else if d>1.e7 then 600 else if d>1.e5 then 500 else if d>1.e3 then 400 else 100;
    for i in 2..w1 repeat(mt:=(i*zd)::List PI;mv:=[yy for yy in mt|yy>=n];z:=sort(removeDuplicates(concat(z,mv)));#z>w2=>break)
    for i in z repeat
        (c:=maxIndex(b:=fracR(x,i)))=0=>1 
        c>m+1                         =>1
        if c<m or(c=m and m<999 and reduce(max,map(denom,b))<xv)then(m:=c;a:=b;xv:=reduce(max,map(denom,a)))
        v:=reduce(+,delete(b,1))
        for j in z repeat
              (c:=1+maxIndex(q:=fracR(v,j)))=1=>1
              member?(b.1,q)                  =>1
              q:=concat(b.1,q)
              if c<m or(c=m and m<999 and reduce(max,map(denom,q))<xv)then(m:=c;a:=q;xv:=reduce(max,map(denom,a)))
    reverse(sort a)
```

the results:

```
(5) -> [[i,Frazione2SommaReciproci(i)] for i in [1/23,2/23,43/48,8/11,5/121,2020/2064,6745/7604,77/79,732/733]]
   (5)
      1   1      2   1  1      43  1 1  1      8  1 1  1  1
   [[--,[--]], [--,[--,---]], [--,[-,-,--]], [--,[-,-,--,--]],
     23  23     23  12 276     48  2 3 16     11  2 6 22 66
      5    1  1   1      505  1 1 1  1    1
    [---,[--,---,---]], [---,[-,-,-,---,----]],
     121  33 121 363     516  2 3 7 602 1204
     6745  1 1  1  1    1      1       77  1 1 1  1  1   1
    [----,[-,-,--,---,-----,------]], [--,[-,-,-,--,---,---]],
     7604  2 3 19 950 72238 570300     79  2 3 8 79 474 632
     732  1 1 1  1   1    1     1
    [---,[-,-,-,--,----,-----,-----]]]
     733  2 3 7 45 7330 20524 26388
                                                      Type: List List Any
                     Time: 0.08 (IN) + 53.45 (EV) + 3.03 (GC) = 56.57 sec
(6) -> Frazione2SommaReciproci(124547787/123456789456123456)
   (6)
        1            1               1                  1
   [---------, ------------, ----------------, -------------------,
    994074172  347757767307  2764751529594496  1142210063701888512
                      1
    -------------------------------------]
    2531144929865351036156388364636113408
                                              Type: List Fraction Integer
         Time: 0.15 (IN) + 78.30 (EV) + 0.02 (OT) + 5.28 (GC) = 83.75 sec
(7) -> Frazione2SommaReciproci(27538/27539)
         1 1 1  1   1     1       1       1
   (7)  [-,-,-,--,----,-------,-------,-------]
         2 3 7 43 1935 3717765 5204871 7105062
                                              Type: List Fraction Integer
                     Time: 0.05 (IN) + 45.43 (EV) + 2.42 (GC) = 47.90 sec
```

It seems many good denominators have as factor divisors of the input fraction denominator.

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 2502 bytes

```
fdn←{1∧÷⍵}⋄fnm←{1∧⍵}⋄ffl←{m←⎕ct⋄⎕ct←0⋄r←⌊⍵⋄⎕ct←m⋄r}⋄divisori←{a[⍋a←{∪×/¨{0=≢⍵:⊂⍬⋄s,(⊂1⌷⍵),¨s←∇1↓⍵}π⍵}⍵]}

r←frRF w;x;y;c;q;i;j
(x i)←w⋄i-←1⋄y←x⋄r←⍬⋄c←0⋄q←fdn x⋄q←q*20
i+←1
→4×⍳∼1000<c+←1⋄→6
j←÷i⋄→2×⍳j>y⋄→2×⍳(⊂j)∊r⋄r←r,(⊂j)⋄y←y-j⋄→0×⍳y=0⋄→5×⍳1≠fnm y⋄→5×⍳(⊂y)∊r⋄r←r,⊂y⋄→0
→2×⍳∼q<i←ffl ÷y
r←⍬

r←fr2SumF x;n;xv;m;d;zd;z;i;b;c;t;v;j;k;q;w1;w2;t;b1
z←r←⍬⋄→0×⍳1≤ffl x
:if 1=fnm x⋄r←,⊂x⋄→0⋄:endif
n←2⌈ffl÷x⋄xv←m←999⋄d←fdn x⋄zd←divisori d
w1←1000⋄w2←50⋄:if d>1.e10⋄w2←700⋄:elseif d>1.e7⋄w2←600⋄:elseif d>1.e5⋄w2←500⋄:elseif d>1.e3⋄w2←400⋄:elseif d>1.e2⋄w2←100⋄:endif
:for i :in ⍳w1⋄z←∪z∪k/⍨{⍵≥n}¨k←i×zd⋄:if w2<≢z⋄:leave⋄:endif⋄:endfor
z←∪z∪zd⋄z←z[⍋z]
:for i :in z
    :if 0=c←≢b←frRF x i ⋄:continue⋄:endif
    :if      c>m+1      ⋄:continue⋄:endif
    :if      c<m        ⋄m←c⋄r←b⋄xv←⌈/fdn¨b
    :elseif (c=m)∧(m<999)
         :if xv>t←⌈/fdn¨b⋄m←c⋄r←b⋄xv←t⋄:endif
    :endif
    :if c≤2⋄:continue⋄:endif
    v←↑+/1↓b⋄b1←(⊂↑b)
    :for j :in z
       :if 1=c←1+≢q←frRF v j⋄:continue⋄:endif
       :if        b1∊q      ⋄:continue⋄:endif
       q←b1,q
       :if  c<m⋄m←c⋄r←q     ⋄xv←⌈/fdn¨q
       :elseif (c=m)∧(m<999)
           :if xv>t←⌈/fdn¨q⋄m←c⋄r←q⋄xv←t⋄:endif
       :endif
    :endfor
:endfor
→0×⍳1≥≢r⋄r←r[⍋fdn¨r]
```

Traslation from AXIOM code for this problem, to APL, using for the first time
(for me) the fraction type (that is bignum...).

103r233 means the fraction 103/233. Test:

```
  ⎕fmt fr2SumF 1r23
┌1────┐
│ 1r23│
└~────┘
  ⎕fmt fr2SumF 2r23
┌2──────────┐
│ 1r12 1r276│
└~──────────┘
  ⎕fmt fr2SumF 43r48
┌3────────────┐
│ 1r2 1r3 1r16│
└~────────────┘
  fr2SumF 8r11
1r2 1r6 1r22 1r66 
  fr2SumF 5r121
1r33 1r121 1r363 
  fr2SumF 2020r2064
1r2 1r3 1r7 1r602 1r1204 
  fr2SumF 6745r7604
1r2 1r3 1r19 1r950 1r72238 1r570300 
  fr2SumF 77r79
1r2 1r3 1r8 1r79 1r474 1r632 
  fr2SumF 732r733
1r2 1r3 1r7 1r45 1r7330 1r20524 1r26388 
  fr2SumF 27538r27539
1r2 1r3 1r7 1r43 1r1935 1r3717765 1r5204871 1r7105062 
  fr2SumF 124547787r123456789456123456
1r994074172 1r347757767307 1r2764751529594496 1r1142210063701888512 
  1r2531144929865351036156388364636113408
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/), 340 bytes

```
f:=function(b,l)local x,R;if l=1 then if IsInt(b)then
return[[b]];fi;return[];fi;R:=[];for x in[Int(b)+1..Int(l*b)]do
UniteSet(R,List(Filtered(f(b*x/(x-b),l-1),d->not x in d),s->UnionSet([x],s)));od;return
R;end;e:=function(n,d)local l,R;l:=0;repeat l:=l+1;R:=f(d/n,l);until R<>[];return
Filtered(R,s->s[l]=Minimum(List(R,s->s[l])))[1];end;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@xbsMgEIZ3PwUjJDgpW2Vij5UitQtVJ8RgB2iRLkdkY8lv74JrRd3@Q/x33/fdP9bVN62f8ZZCRDpwYBBvPZCFKxk8gVaQ9OOQ5HydrpjowMpcjS7NI2o9GCN9kPu4ZdW0JcSRLCSg/isdxelUEhwGZmysvjAk9@kSVfw9TIm@BUhudJZ6OhyWM13qgXGoBeO27jCmbRexjE91l7sRS1cvhk@MMRntTlAp6dBK988Jud2dIDtB077kvw/XJ5IzHEXh9dSeMbvLGVMAoi5dNtg3PslUuT1pMO1HwHCf73Qjfz5nEC3Mdn9dHX3lQjD5Cw)

The entry function is `e`, which takes two parameters, the numerator and denominator in that order, as required. 2 characters could be golfed (replace `n,d` with `q` and `d/n` with `1/q`) if I may make `e` take the fraction `n/d` direct, and 2 more if I may make `e` take its reciprocal `d/n`. But this goes against the question.

The helper function `f` returns a list of the ways to represent `1/b` in `l` distinct terms.