# Longest sequence of Egyptian fractions with n as denominator

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, rational-numbers

##### Background

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction): An Egyptian fraction is the sum of distinct unit fractions. That is, each fraction in the expression has a numerator equal to 1 and a denominator that is a positive integer, and all the denominators differ from each other. The value of an expression of this type is a positive rational number a/b. Every positive rational number can be represented by an Egyptian fraction.

##### Task

Write a function that given \$ n \$, outputs the longest sequence of Egyptian fractions (that sum up to 1) where \$ n \$ is the largest denominator.

##### Rules

- If no solution exists, you may output anything or nothing except any real number
- If there are two or more solutions, output any one of them
- Assume \$ n \$ is not two and is a natural number
- Your output must be in descending order
- You must not output duplicates
- Each individual fraction must be separated by a plus symbol (`+`). Spaces are optional. However the plus symbol should not come after the last fraction.
- Your code does not need to practically handle very high \$ n \$, but it must work in theory for all \$ n \$ for which a solution exists
- You may use any [standard I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden

##### Examples

`6` ⟶ `1/2 + 1/3 + 1/6`

`15` ⟶ `1/3 + 1/4 + 1/6 + 1/10 + 1/12 + 1/15`

`20`:

```
1/4 + 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/9 + 1/10 + 1/15 + 1/18 + 1/20
```

or

```
1/3 + 1/5 + 1/9 + 1/10 + 1/12 + 1/15 + 1/18 + 1/20
```

`2016`:

```
1/15 + 1/22 + 1/24 + 1/25 + 1/30 + 1/32 + 1/33 + 1/39 + 1/40 + 1/42 + 1/44 + 1/45 + 1/48 + 1/55 + 1/56 + 1/60 + 1/63 + 1/64 + 1/65 + 1/66 + 1/70 + 1/72 + 1/78 + 1/80 + 1/84 + 1/85 + 1/88 + 1/90 + 1/91 + 1/96 + 1/99 + 1/104 + 1/110 + 1/112 + 1/119 + 1/120 + 1/130 + 1/132 + 1/135 + 1/136 + 1/150 + 1/154 + 1/156 + 1/160 + 1/165 + 1/168 + 1/170 + 1/171 + 1/175 + 1/180 + 1/182 + 1/184 + 1/189 + 1/190 + 1/195 + 1/198 + 1/200 + 1/208 + 1/210 + 1/220 + 1/225 + 1/230 + 1/238 + 1/240 + 1/260 + 1/270 + 1/272 + 1/275 + 1/288 + 1/299 + 1/300 + 1/306 + 1/320 + 1/324 + 1/325 + 1/330 + 1/340 + 1/345 + 1/368 + 1/400 + 1/405 + 1/434 + 1/459 + 1/465 + 1/468 + 1/476 + 1/480 + 1/495 + 1/496 + 1/527 + 1/575 + 1/583 + 1/672 + 1/765 + 1/784 + 1/795 + 1/810 + 1/840 + 1/875 + 1/888 + 1/900 + 1/918 + 1/920 + 1/975 + 1/980 + 1/990 + 1/1000 + 1/1012 + 1/1050 + 1/1088 + 1/1092 + 1/1100 + 1/1104 + 1/1113 + 1/1125 + 1/1196 + 1/1200 + 1/1224 + 1/1258 + 1/1309 + 1/1330 + 1/1386 + 1/1395 + 1/1425 + 1/1440 + 1/1470 + 1/1480 + 1/1484 + 1/1488 + 1/1512 + 1/1620 + 1/1650 + 1/1680 + 1/1728 + 1/1729 + 1/1800 + 1/1824 + 1/1836 + 1/1840 + 1/1848 + 1/1850 + 1/1870 + 1/1890 + 1/1950 + 1/1980 + 1/1995 + 1/2000 + 1/2016
```

or

```
...
```

##### Criteria

1. For first place: shortest code in bits wins
2. For second place: fastest code wins.

   So if a code is the shortest and fastest, the second fastest code will be given 2<sup>nd</sup> place

P.S: The background definition and some rules are taken from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6215) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241222) question respectively.

Comment: Nice first challenge! Some suggestions: from the testcases, it seems like \$n\$ has to be the greatest denominator, and they don't have to be consecutive — you should clarify that in the challenge text. Additionally, I'd suggest having a looser output format — I don't see why we can't output as `[2,3,6]`, for example, or why the order is important. For the scoring criteria, saying "shortest code wins, with time as tiebreaker" would be clearer. You should ...

Comment: (cont.) clarify on which tests the speed is determined. It's quite unlikely that a language will have two solutions with the same length but significantly different time, so the tiebreaker might not be relevant. I suggest first posting challenges to the sandbox in the future

Comment: @CommandMaster Thank you for your valuable feedback. I have changed the framing to remove 'consecutive' as it is not required. For the scoring criteria, I have omitted the tiebreaker part. Also I agree for you on the output format, but someone has already submitted an answer so its too late now, but I will keep that in mind. Thank you for bringing my attention to the sandbox.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that `1/3 + 1/5 + 1/9 + 1/10 + 1/12 + 1/15 + 1/18 + 1/20` is an equally valid solution for your third test case?

Comment: @JosWoolley I have added a rule saying that output any one solution when 2 or more exists, and mentioned the example

Comment: Similar question: [Egyptian fraction representations of 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241222/egyptian-fraction-representations-of-1)

Comment: @138Aspen Already linked it in my question, though it is about the number of fractions

Comment: IANAM, but `1/1` is a valid unit fraction, so there is always a solution, even for `n=1`.  Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `R`, 89 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 11.125 bytes

```
ṗ't?=;Ė'∑1=;t\+j
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJSPSIsIiIsIuG5lyd0Pz07xJYn4oiRMT07dFxcK2oiLCIiLCIzIl0=)

+~3 bytes due to reading the specs

Me when when fraction type automatically. Powerset is sorted by length by default, so the last item is guaranteed to be the longest.

Comment: Is the tail really guaranteed to be the longest sequence? (I asked myself a similar question when writing my answer but decided to explicitly test the lengths for now.)

Comment: @Arnauld Vyxal's power set built-in sorts the subsets by length.

Comment: [powerset actually doesn't sort by length](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLhuZciLCIiLCJbMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNl0iXQ==) due to needing to work nicely with infinite lists.

Comment: How do you distinguish between the valid output `1` (aka `1/1`) for \$n=1\$ and invalid outputs `1` for \$n=2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,...\$?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen that's handled by powerset sorting subsets by length. `[1]` will always be in the list of valid subsets, but it won't always be the longest/last item.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 103 bytes, \$O(2^n)\$

Returns an empty string if there's no solution.

```javascript
f=(n,a=o=[],p=0,q=1)=>n?f(n-1,["1/"+n,...a],p*n+q,q*n,p&&f(n-1,a,p,q))&&o.join`+`:o=p-q|o[a.length]?o:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpBDoIwEEDRvcdg0XRgqNREFyQjByEkNAgIaWZaIa68ezVxZdy@/1f3dNvwWMJestzGlCbSjI6E2g4DVRjJAl25mTSXFtvMHrOC0RjjPj3nImLMGYNS38FhwAiglJhVFu6LvhYKZXxJ64wfed7vXSO1S4PwJn40XmY96QvA4Vfs@Y9OFUB6Aw)

Comment: Is this a bruteforce \$O(2^n)\$ solution?

Comment: Yes it is. I've added the time complexity in the header.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 50 bytes, *O(2ⁿ)*

```
Ｎθ≔ΦＥ…Ｘ²⊖θＸ²θ⊕⌕Ａ⮌⍘ι²1⁼ΠιΣ÷Πιιυ¿υ⪫⁺1/Ｉ§υ⌕ＥυＬι⌈ＥυＬι+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/LTsNADLzzFaucvGJRlUqcegqUSqkoitovWLImtbRx2n2E/n1wggRCnOzxeMbj9mxDO1g/TTVfcnrL/TsGuOrNXRUjdQw78kkmB3uBo@UOoRk@Ba@N2mIbsEdO6ESgjfphFlTzL70jdpX3cMQRQ0R4shFPKRB3QEat5/WiLPRcX67Z@ghNGFxuE5CMTrmHmtOWRnL4hyG9aLLEpQ8FWatGTBPsB2JofI5QlKvCqGcbE1SpZoc3yEbNeZaXpH9F7tJZ7MToYG/Uy7V/lP4@VNxLyM00lY/Tw@i/AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔ΦＥ…Ｘ²⊖θＸ²θ⊕⌕Ａ⮌⍘ι²1⁼ΠιΣ÷Πιιυ
```

Get the powerset of `[1..n-1]` and see which sets' reciprocals sum to `1` when `1/n` is included.

```
¿υ⪫⁺1/Ｉ§υ⌕ＥυＬι⌈ＥυＬι+
```

If any were found then output the longest.

53 bytes for a version that is twice as fast because it gets the powerset of `[2..n-1]`:

```
Ｎθ≔ΦＥ⊗…Ｘ²⁻θ²Ｘ²⊖θ⊕⌕Ａ⮌⍘ι²1⁼ΠιΣ÷Πιιυ¿υ⪫⁺1/Ｉ§υ⌕ＥυＬι⌈ＥυＬι+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/bSsNAEIbvfYolV7MYkRS86lU0FiJGQvsE22SaDmxmmz3Evn2ctqKId8P3M/@hOxrfOWOXpeZTih9p3KOHSa/vyhBoYNiQjUIac4LKpb3FHraGB4TWfQpf5aohTgGmXK20ztUPrrDzOCJH@Zi0vmg1/6INcV9aC1uc0QeEZxNwFz3xAPRtlRXZ9e11SsYGaL3rUxeBBO3SCDXHimbq8Y9Ct6gkC@igIGnVimmEN0cMrZWmWfGY5erFhAhlrLnHM6RcXfpcV8r9jjzEo9iJUWPONEraP0nfgrJ7KbleluJpeZjtFw) Link is to verbose version of code.

<s>71</s> 66 bytes for an algorithm that is slightly faster because it stops considering fractions once the sum exceeds `1` (I don't know how this affects the time complexity though):

```
Ｎθ≔⟦⟦θ⟧⟧ηＦ…²θＦ⮌η«≔⁺κ⟦ι⟧κ≔⁻Σ÷ΠκκΠκζ¿‹ζ⁰⊞ηκ¿∧¬ζ›ＬκＬυ≔⊞ＯΦκμθυ»⪫⁺1/Ｉυ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9PT8MwDMXP9FNYPTkiCIbEaacJBBoao4Jj1UNpvSZqm6z508MQn724oxMXK372@8WvUqWrbNlN09YcY9jH/oscDmKdbLzXjcE8H4pCgmLlYB3gR2kawnsJgxDwp9BIzhMqFr6Tq8WXddFjKyHXhZDQsv0yedOGR5@xx60JT3rUNWHmbB2rgO15l8u/wM1pdusD4I68x5OEO/4qi16hWtDUeYJ5Y2Nq3NuAJ7a9OCoDp9mRaYI6s5dnFAy4HMqc9yO5MliHz7qbHXx3L@aIEiLjf5LMaRPw1eolWLq6TSU8lj7MLAnpdSrEeppWD9PN2P0C) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ≔⟦⟦θ⟧⟧η
```

Input `n` and start with `1/n` as a required fraction.

```
Ｆ…²θＦ⮌η«
```

For each integer from `2` to `n-1`, loop over all of the sets so far.

```
≔⁺κ⟦ι⟧κ≔⁻Σ÷ΠκκΠκζ
```

Create a new set containing the current integer and calculate the excess of the sum of reciprocals.

```
¿‹ζ⁰⊞ηκ
```

If the excess is negative i.e. the sum is less than `1` then add this to the list of sets to check next iteration.

```
¿∧¬ζ›ＬκＬυ≔⊞ＯΦκμθυ
```

If the excess is zero i.e. the sum is `1` and this set is longer than any previously found set then set this as the longest found set so far.

```
»⪫⁺1/Ｉυ+
```

Output the longest set found.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 246 bytes:

```py
def f(n):
 q,t=[([*range(2,n)],[],1-(1/n))],[]
 while q:
  d,c,r=q.pop(0)
  if[]==d:continue
  if round(r,5)==0:t+=[c];continue
  if(U:=r-(1/d[0]))>=0:q+=[(d[1:],c+[d[0]],U)]
  q+=[(d[1:],c,r)]
 return'+'.join(f'1/{i}'for i in max(t,key=len)+[n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BTsMwEETv@QrfskuWNikqQkHmL3qyfKhimxrK2lk5ggrx7SGphFRuM2@eNPlSTokfnrLMs/NBBWDsKzVS0QbMnRz51cOOGC0ZS909dFvGa6nU5ymevRoXXTkaSPS4ySlDiwuIwVitXT8kLpEnf0VK0sQOhPaodduXRpvBPv9T4NBrWV@caS3iy6KNiwbOdL2loTErt3TA5V/dLiQrEl8m4bqpN28pMoS6237HnzokUVFFVh/HLyj07i/67BkbwxbnLJELBHhErP5yt78puxZx/gU)

Comment: Is this DFS approach O(2^n)?

Comment: @Anm Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 168 bytes, \$O(2^n)\$

```
=LET(
    a,SEQUENCE(,A1),
    b,IF(MOD(INT(SEQUENCE(2^A1,,0)/2^(a-1)),2),1/a,),
    IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("+",,
        "1/"&TOCOL(1/TAKE(FILTER(b,TAKE(b,,-1)*(MMULT(b,TOCOL(a^0))=1)),-1),2))
    ,"")
)
```

Input in cell `A1`.

Comment: What would the time complexity of this be?

Comment: @Anm Apologies. There was an issue with the previous solution, which I've now fixed and also added the order.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>23</s> 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LæʒIå}DzOT.òÏéθ„1/ì'+ý
```

Will output nothing if there are no results.

There is a bug in the filter builtin `ʒ` for decimals `1.0` (which should be 05AB1E-truthy). So the second filter `ʒ...Θ}` has been replaced with `D...Ï` for -1 byte, without changing its functionality.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9vc2FiaWX//0zDpsqSScOlfUR6T1Quw7LDj8OpzrjigJ4xL8OsJyvDvf//MTU) or [verify test cases until it times out](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9vc2FiaWX/W04@RMKpPyIg4oaSICI//0zDpsqSwq7DpX1Eek9ULsOyw4/Dqc644oCeMS/DrCcrw73/LP8).

**Explanation:**

```python
L          # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 æ         # Get the powerset of this list
  ʒ  }     # Filter this list of lists by:
   Iå      #  It contains the input-integer
  D     Ï  # Filter it further by:
   z       #  Take 1/v for each value `v` in the list
    O      #  Sum them together
     T.ò   #  Round it to 10 decimal digits to account for floating point inaccuracies
           #  (only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
  é        # After the filters: sort the remaining list by length (shortest to longest)
   θ       # Pop and push the last/longest valid list
  „1/ì     # Prepend "1/" in front of each integer
      '+ý '# And join these strings with "+"-delimiter
           # (after which the resulting string is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Nice! Although the question specified that the program may not output any real number if a solution does not exist

Comment: @Anm Good point. It will now output an empty string for invalid results (and I've golfed it by 1 byte as well).

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 345 bytes

Port of [@Ajax1234's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265633/110802) in Scala.

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFNSwMxEL3vrxiKh4SuaVfQw5YUlCoKCn7QU5GSbtIazSbd7KxaZX97nW1BRXNIyHtvMu9N6kI5tbXlOkSEuruIIjhnCrTBi7JBtXBG3DWmMUkSFs9EwI2yHj6TBF6Vg2UOVx7l@AGj9SuQWy/Hn68qQiV3VYwdAQbwhxkd17bGtNtmVPPIeJodZmI48JyPuhKUO@5bQIrk7ck6wyrhgz8v17jh9LhjOi3SyGUltKm6LiO7ZPqXhq5ndjUxhS1JHbmoDT5QOsOO0x9C3IfGa7J9E7QRl6fXF/PpLRcYJqGh2FIOOcoizzHpkjYy7txq8WSU7jo2Y1JUfcmoNyrr0j2V50XaUKTfTGeXt@2IoSjV@9mGzUVtPwyHvO/JHU3faGLWzMpx3csGB7bHRfmynyrr9Xu83QJos4SSps9UXNU5nMaoNrO95pHnMPUWQdLXAK01oeg8W7ITzv8g2fE/6Gi4g9qk3X4B)

```scala
n=>{var q=Queue((2 to n-1 toList,List[Int](),1-1.0/n));var t=List[List[Int]]()
while(q.nonEmpty){val(d,c,r)=q.dequeue;if(d.nonEmpty){if(BigDecimal(r).setScale(5,BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble==0)t=c::t
val u=r-1.0/d.head;if(u>=0)q+=((d.tail,d.head::c,u));q+=((d.tail,c,r))}};(t.maxBy(_.size) :+n).sorted.map(i=>s"1/$i").mkString("+")}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJRa9swFIXf/SsOYQ8ScZWk0D0YUmjpxgYtbCt9CqGo9k2iTZYT@XptGPntmWQ7SdfRJ9u63zn36vjWubZ6vzfluvKMOn6pvLKWcjaVU2XD@smS@t5QQ0lSPf0MBdxp4/AnAQpaYCFchq@OZYZ79sYtMW1rwG/tscnQamfi1tQ8C9w8xavXm6oJ/nIeRC0nWk557ZYkzlM42eEiPCc4g5io8chJKY8dOOv8jqbRq5O0zPPKWILYKFe5T@Wat7IfL8otRJEiT@FlUG1UQZt2CtkTZhEAZeo3QmA0irUCpgbFWjCpHBvXEJ4Nr8ArgqMXhmHyOmbZS3cgW1NrfG2WN5SbUlvhpaqJ70P8JC5SnCrqR9W4IqR6VxWkvlzdfn58@CYVV11wmE4xfj0Xh2vkyDLwv/1ORLx0Eyh/SLNQK9KFPAJxtAaXb4yBDYZTiBAHa2NTdLLYKsTXyJN@l7yjaGM@cB21Sw4jlfol/rQwGKvwfr0Vj8qSW/JKIhuii6@HVB2WlYrArYXB9BL1YDL6YAZSlb@6HRSD4SB22iX9lpZhZYX2yzrDlfd6O@u4edjaB2f4uLPrcMrWiYX42I96Oplc/Hd0PpZdm91@/xc)

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

object Main {
  def f(n: Int): String = {
    var q: Queue[(List[Int], List[Int], Double)] = Queue((List.range(2, n), List(), 1 - (1.0/n)))
    var t: List[List[Int]] = List()
    while (q.nonEmpty) {
      val (d, c, r) = q.dequeue()
      if (d.isEmpty) {
        // if d is empty, continue with the next iteration
      } else if (BigDecimal(r).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble == 0) {
        t = c :: t
      } else {
        val u = r - (1.0/d.head)
        if (u >= 0) {
          q += ((d.tail, d.head :: c, u))
        }
        q += ((d.tail, c, r))
      }
    }
    val maxList = t.maxBy(_.length) :+ n
    maxList.sorted.map(i => s"1/$i").mkString("+")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(f(6))
    println(f(15))
    println(f(20))
  }
}
```